# Connect the Seekbar to the EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, seekbar

I need help connecting the seekbar to the edit text. I want to limit the number of lines of the text.

On the seekbar, I put the number from 1-50, and for example, I put the number on 20, the number of lines is limited to 20 lines.

Answer (score 0):

in your xml file add this code

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/editText2" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:maxLines="20" 
android:lines="20">
```

or programmatically

```
editText.setLines(maxlines); //maxlines=20
```